# Converting date numbers to a date object

Tags: untagged

In Mathematica 13.3, I've a number, say 20231114, and I want to convert it to a Wolfram Language (WL) `DateObject`. My first attempt failed:

```js
FromDateString[ToString[20231114], {"Year", "Month", "Day" }]
```

This fails with Mathematica complaining that [image]

As `"Year"`, `"Month"` and `"Day"` refer to length delimited parts, I expected this to work even without explicitly specifying separators, i.e. leaving them out.

> BTW: The "Delimiter" option is broken in Mathematica/WL 13.3.

My question is: Is there a way to use `FromDateString` to convert such a date string formatted as "CCYYMMDD"?

And, in general a date time string formatted as "CCYYMMDDHHmmSS" etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
FromDateString[ToString[20231114], DateFormat -> "ISODate"]
```

and

```
FromDateString[ToString[20231114235559], 
  <|"Elements" -> {"Year", "Month", "Day", "Hour", "Minute", "Second"}, 
                   "Delimiters" -> {""}
 |>
]
```

do work.

Comment: Also `FromDateString[ToString[20231114]<>"haha",{"Year","Month","Day","haha"}]`